# Script to normalize subfields in CSV using pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

OK, I know this is simple to do in python/pandas, but I haven't found a good example.

CSV contains:

```
app_name, owners, App_servers, DB_Servers, databases
app1, bob;larry;alice, mars;jupiter, Gorp;Gulp, roadrunner
app2, jane, mercury, Glitch
app3, , venus; uranus, Glint, tweety
app4, jennifer,,,tweety;roadrunner
```

So: Always an app_name, all other fields may contain multiple values separated by a semicolon.

I need to denormalize this into 2 files:

```
app_name, owner
app_name, server, server_type # where server_type is either appsrv, dbsrv, dbstore
```

I've got the file open in a data frame, but having trouble figuring out the best way to parse and write to separate data frames. I suspect that there is some easy way to split the subfields using map/apply, but I'm just brute forcing it with loops (did I mention I'm new to all this?).

I'm having trouble understanding how to move the cursor/record pointer in the output data frames as I loop through them. I've gotten close by building the record and using an append function, but its pretty fugly and doesn't seem to work as expected. I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something obvious like doing this via a map/appay/lambda function... but I haven't seen a good example and it may be that that's not the way to go.

Here is my code so far (yes, I'm aware the logic doesn't work):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('max_columns', 50)
cols = [omitted]
# idf is input data frame, odf is output data frame
idf = pd.read_csv('2014 App Inv.csv', skiprows=1, usecols=cols)
odf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['AppName','AltAppName','AppServer', 'DBServer','DBInstance','CIO'])
for i0 in idf:
    appname = idf["Asset Name"] #This is returning the entire column!
    cio = idf["App Owners"]
    y = split(idf["AppServers"],";")
    for i1 in y:
       x = split(idf["DB Servers"],";")
       for i2 in x:
           w = split(idf["Databases"],";")
           for i3 in w: 
                r = {appname, altappname, i1, i2, i3, cio}
                print r
                odf = odf.append(r, ignore_index=True)
```

OK, I'm not asking anyone to write the program for me, but I'm having trouble understanding the best/easiest/simplest way to do this. I'm sure there is an example somewhere, I just need to be pointed to it.

As always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would make the required imports and open the CSV file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, string

filedescriptor1 = open("myfile.csv", 'r')
```

Then, I would simply navigate through every line of this file descriptor and split the words between commas.

```
for line in filedescriptor1:
    splitted = line.split(',') # here we splitting the line into pieces between ','
    app_name = splitted[0] # as it is the first field of the line
    owner = splitted[1] # second field...and most of the same for the rest fields
```

From this point, you can just write to a file each parameters for each line or store it into an array and print it (or do whatever you want with that) at the end of the **for** loop.

Comment: It may be a good idea to make sure that your file handles are closed in any scenario.

Comment: @cel I can't get your point...what do you mean? Closing **filedescriptor1** at the end of the loop?

Comment: you usually use a `with open(fpath) as filedescriptor1` block to make sure that `filedescriptor1` get closed properly. Your code opens the file descriptor but never explicitly closes it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I searched until I found an example and as I expected, it was simple:
:
    # idf = pd.dataframe
    for idx, row in idf.**iterrows**(): #This lets me loop through the dataframe

All I really needed was to understand how to move the cursor (in SQL terminology).

Until I learn how to use map/apply, looping through a pandas dataframe is good enough.

Good PANDAS training here: [Alfred Essa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhkchS9gSYk&list=PLyBBc46Y6aAz54aOUgKXXyTcEmpMisAq3&index=2)
Good short blog post on PANDAS here: [Greg Reda](http://www.gregreda.com/2013/10/26/working-with-pandas-dataframes/)